# Why am I still running kernel `3.16.0-28-generic` on 14.10 although I have -29- and -33- installed?

Tags: kernel, 14.10, versions

I just received another kernel update (3.16.0-33-generic) I installed with `apt-get dist-upgrade`.
I rebooted and checked with `uname -r` which gave me the output `3.16.0-28-generic`.
I know from `update-grub` and the files in `/boot/` that I have the following kernels installed on my system:

- 3.16.0-33-generic (installed this morning with dist-upgrade)
- 3.16.0-29-generic
- 3.16.0-28-generic (currently used)
- 3.16.0-25-generic
- 3.16.0-24-generic

Why am I not running the latest kernel version? How can I change this?
And which old kernels can I remove and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting "Advanced options for Ubuntu" each time you log in will let you select one from the installed kernels.

But to make it the default, Try [Boot repair Disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) from here. Or you might need to code the Grub.

For more details about using Boot repair Disk, go [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)

Removing old kernels can be done by typing `sudo apt-get autoremove` on the terminal.

Comment: Do I have to use the CD? I have it installed too... And I did use autoremove many times.

Comment: You have installed boot repair disk?

Comment: Yes!? It can be installed like a normal package. I can't remember if I had to add a PPA though...

Comment: It didn't work? have you tried the manual option on it?

Comment: I just ran the recommended repair and will try to reboot now. That might take 15 min or so, as I can't boot while the graphic card is hot...

Comment: **Solved! It was a GRUB problem: I have two OS (Ubuntu and Kali) I dual-boot and the active GRUB is the one of Kali. So when I update-grub under Ubuntu, it does nothing... Now the boot-repair replaced it with a new GRUB belonging to Ubuntu. That solved it and now I am running the newest kernel, -33-.**